# Followed tutorial but can't get MainActivityBinding class generated for ViewBinding

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

Following the exact documentation but can't figure out why it's not working...
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The class is never generated for my `MainActivity`
`activity_main.xml`

[image]

I've tried cleaning the project, rebuilding it. Even invalidating cache + restart, but have no idea why it's still not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added `tools:viewBindingIgnore="true"` into the layout, so the binding class for the layout is not created.

Delete `tools:viewBindingIgnore="true"` and try again.

Comment: I'm so stupid. I glossed over the text and thought we needed to add that into the layout for it to be generated... Thanks.